# How to label points with two lines in tilemill

Tags: tilemill

I am designing a map in Tilemill. I want to label my POIs with tow lines. If I am using

```
text-wrap-width:1;
```

then its breaking the labels with each word as a new line. Such as if the label is "One Two Three Four" then its showing like

One
Two
Three
Four

But I want to visualize like the following

One Two
Three Four

Sometimes its very hectic for viewers. Is there any way to label those with two lines always?

Thanks